# How do I conditionally render part of my CSS class

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, pseudo-class, conditional-rendering

How can I make all of the css inside the following hover psuedoclass conditionally render when a variable (data) is not null? I have the following styles in my React Component (which uses Material UI makeStyles:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
      card: {
        height: '100%',
        '&:hover': {
          background: theme.palette.secondary.light,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          '& $hide': {
            opacity: 1,
            transition: '0.6s',
          },
        },
      },
}));

const myComponent = ({data}) => {
     const classes=useStyles({data});
     <div className={classes.card}>
          Hello
     </div>
}
```

I have tried using something along the following lines, but with all the back ticks and apostrophes it's not working at all!:

```
  card: {
    height: '100%',
    position: 'relative',
    ({ data}) => (data && `'&:hover': {
      background: ${theme.palette.secondary.light},
      cursor: 'pointer', 
      '& $hide': {
        opacity: 1,
        transition: '0.6s',
      },
    },`),
  },
```

Many thanks,

Katie

Comment: While I'm not completely familiar with this syntax, to me it appears that the simplest solution would be to conditionally attach the class. Something like `className={data ? classes.card : null}` perhaps?

Comment: Thank you Pixell! This was a lovely, simple solution. I have separated out the class into two classes (hover information in one and the rest in the other), then applied the class as follows:
      <div  className={`${classes.card} ${dataType && classes.cardWithLink}`}  >
It works perfectly. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) package

```
import cx from 'classnames';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
      cardWithData: {
        height: '100%',
        '&:hover': {
          background: theme.palette.secondary.light,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          '& $hide': {
            opacity: 1,
            transition: '0.6s',
          },
        },
      },
     card: {
       height: '100%',
     }
}));

const myComponent = ({data}) => {
     const classes=useStyles();
     <div className={cx({[classes.cardWithData]: Boolean(data), [classes.card]:!data})}>
          Hello
     </div>
}
```